# Собрать в массив из рекурсии

Tags: php

```
   function get_data_dynamic_link($parent){

        $var = array();

        $db_query = "select * from ".DB_PREF."dynamic 
                     where id_parent = ".$parent." ";

        list($kolvo, $data_prop) = obr_db_query_select_one_assoc($db_query);

        if($kolvo){
            $var[] = $data_prop['id'];
            $var[] = get_data_dynamic_link($data_prop['id_properties']);
        }

        return $var; 
   }
```

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, почему данный код возвращает массив с наращиванием вложенностей

```
array(2) { 
    [0]=> string(1) "6"
    [1]=> array(2) { 
         [0]=> string(1) "7" 
         [1]=> array(0) { 
         }
    } 
}
```

когда мне нужно, чтобы было так

```
array(2) {
    [0]=> string(1) "6"
    [1]=>  string(1) "7"  
}
```

Что нужно исправить ? спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Без  тестовых данных проверить сложно,

```
function get_data_dynamic_link($parent){

    static $var = [];        

    $db_query = "select * from ".DB_PREF."dynamic 
                 where id_parent = ".$parent." ";

    list($kolvo, $data_prop) = obr_db_query_select_one_assoc($db_query);

    if($kolvo){
        $var[] = $data_prop['id'];
        get_data_dynamic_link($data_prop['id_properties']);
    }

    return $var; 
}
```

Определите массив результата как статическую переменную, тогда она будет в единственном экземпляре доступна среди всех вызовов функции, в т.ч. рекурсивных.  А в конце не добавляйте результат вызовы рекурсии в сам массив, а просто вызывайте метод.

Answer (score 1):

Есть несколько вариантов решения, через ссылки, статические переменные или передачей исходного массива в функцию, мне кажется для начинающего 3-й вариант будет самый понятный:

```
function get_data_dynamic_link($parent, $array = array()){

    $db_query = "select * from ".DB_PREF."dynamic 
                 where id_parent = ".$parent." ";

    list($kolvo, $data_prop) = obr_db_query_select_one_assoc($db_query);

    if ($kolvo){
        array_push($array, $data_prop['id']);
        $array = get_data_dynamic_link($data_prop['id_properties'], $array);
    }

    return $array; 
}
```

Мы получаем массив и добавляем в него элемент, если массив не передаем, создается новый

Comment: именовать переменную `$array` еще трешевей чем `$var`.

Comment: @teran то есть `$kolvo` нормальная? это пример как бы, автор в праве заменить обратно на `$var`, я показал реализацию

Comment: она хотя бы осмысленное название имеет, называли бы `$result` да и все. Если уж говорите в посте про начинающих, то как раз таки вдалбливать в головы надо, что имена переменных должны соответствовать их назначению и содержанию